# Creating file at a specific location inside windows store app installation folder

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs, windows-store

I am creating a `Windows Store Javascript App`. I want to create a file inside apps installation location.

I created uri:

```
var p = "ms-appx:///" + filepath;
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(p);
```

How to create a file at this uri??

I know how to create it inside apps installation folder but not inside any subfolders

```
var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current;
var localFolder = package.installedLocation;    
localFolder.createFileAsync("dataFile.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just learnt that  [Apps don't have write access to their installed directory.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a32d16fd-7855-4fce-9091-8067f712a1b6/access-denied-on-windowsstoragefileiowritetextasync-to-write-a-text-file-in-a-local-application)

Comment: Right. This is common across all Microsoft platforms now.